# Is there any way to pass optional parameters to handlers in apple script when we have to pass only one parameter

Tags: macos, applescript

I have written a handler

```
on test(action)

  set x to "0"
  set y to "1"
  if action = "multiply"
     return  x*y
  end if 
  return x+y
end test
```

I want to call some places as test() without any parameters where it returns sum and in other places I want to pass parameters as "multiply".

So i am looking for a way if i can set optional parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optional parameters in AppleScript handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035959/optional-parameters-in-applescript-handlers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Optional Labelled Parameters

Optional parameters are possible if you declare a handler using [*labelled parameters*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW22).  However, there needs to be at least two parameters for this to be valid.

For example:

```
    on array from a as integer : 1 to b as integer
        local a, b
        set L to {}

        repeat with i from a to b
            set end of L to i
        end repeat

        L
    end
```

This handler creates a list of integers.  It takes two parameters, `a` and `b`, of which `a` is an optional parameter, assigned a default value of `1`.

Thus,

```
    array from 4 to 10
```

would produce this list:

```
    {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

whereas:

```
    array to 10
```

would produce a list as if you had called the handler with `array from 1 to 10`:

```
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

You can make both `a` and `b` optional, however at least one parameter **must** be included when you call the handler.

*`from`* and *`to`* are the parameter **labels**, of which there are many predefined prepositions that can be used to label parameters.  These can be called in any order:

```
    array from 10 to 1
```

is identical to

```
    array from 1 to 10
```

and *doesn't* reverse the list order.

Other labels include:

```
about, above, against, apart from, around, aside from, at, 
below, beneath, beside, between, by, for, from, instead of, 
into, on, onto, out of, over, since, thru, under
```

and you can define your own labels that are used along with the keyword **`given`**, but I'll leave you to read about that using the link above that I left.

#### 2. Your `test()` handler

Your handler only accepts one parameter, so it sadly cannot be optional.  However, if you introduce `x` and `y` as parameters, then you *can* make the `action` optional:

```
    on test over {x, y} given function:action : "add"
        local x, y, action

        if action = "multiply" then return x * y

        x + y
    end test
```

Then:

```
    test over {2, 5} given function:"multiply" --> 10
    test over {2, 5} --> 7
```

#### 3. Handler As Parameter

This is a side-note, and not directly related to your question, but partially related to what you're doing.

Handlers can be passed as parameters too, however cannot be made optional.  I'll leave this script with you to overlook and analyse, and introduce you to the possibilities that this can open up.  If you've ever used a functional language like *Haskell* or *Lisp*, this will be very familiar:

```
    to apply to {x as number, y as number} given function:func as handler
        local x, y, func

        script
            property fn : func
        end script

        result's fn(x, y)
    end apply

    to add(x, y)
        x + y
    end add

    to multiply(x, y)
        x * y
    end multiply
```

It's no way near as powerful as what proper functional languages can do, but it is a lot more powerful than what most AppleScripters realise AppleScript can do:

```
    apply to {5, 2} given function:multiply
```

But this is beyond the remit of this question, so I'll leave your imagination to ponder why this construct might be more special than it appears at first.